# Click on button to change to table view in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have two button in my program(**figure A**), I want to change to a table view(**figure B**) when I click on one button. Can someone please advise how to do that?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple actually. In the button's handler method, create the table view controller and display it modally or push it on the navigation stack.

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayTableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)displayTableView:(id)sender
{
      MyTableViewController* myTVC = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myTVC" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myTVC animated:YES];
     //[self.navigationController pushViewController:myTVC animated:YES]; //2nd option
    [myTVC release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have two questions. (1) The first line of your code is adding the event handler to the button, seem that it can done by interface builder? (2) When should I use presentModalViewController and pushViewController? Thanks

Comment: 1) Yes, it can be done via IB. Expose the button as IBOutlet & connect 'touch up inside' in Sent Events in IB with the button. 2) Depends on your application's UI design. i would prefer push on iPhone & modal on iPad.